# Hibernate how to map Enum key and value in Map<enum,enum> as a String

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

How can i map enums as string to database in Map in Hibernate 
I now how to map key with @MapKeyEnumerated, but how to do the same with value of my map ?

Part of Model code :

```
@MapKeyClass(value = Allergen.class)
@MapKeyEnumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
@ElementCollection(targetClass = AllergicStatus.class)
private Map<Allergen,AllergicStatus> allergens;
```

Where Allergen and AllergicStatus is enum

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answer for my own question is @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)

```
@MapKeyClass(value = Allergen.class)
@MapKeyEnumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
@ElementCollection(targetClass = AllergicStatus.class)
@Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
private Map<Allergen,AllergicStatus> allergens;
```